# NSLog is throwing error while trying to disable it in the project

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, nslog

I want to disable all the `NSLog` in my project. In the project I have added one library. When I tried to disable all the `NSLog` in the project other than the library it is working fine.
But when I try to add it in the library project it is throwing error.

I tried this code

```
// Enable debug (NSLog)
//#define DEVLOPENV 1 // comment this to disable the nslogs

#ifdef DEVLOPENV
#   define NSLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"\n%s : [Line - %d] \n" fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define NSLog(fmt, ...)
#endif
```

The xcode is throwing 
[image]
Can anyone please help me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the macro is expanded at compile time, your code will look like this:

```
dict1 ? [temp addObject:dict1] : ;
```

Not providing a "else" value for the ternary operator is not possible, hence the error.

You could define your macro like so to work around the problem:

```
#ifdef DEVLOPENV
#   define NSLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"\n%s : [Line - %d] \n" fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define NSLog(fmt, ...) (void)(0)
#endif
```

Your code will then look like:

```
dict1 ? [temp addObject:dict1] : (void)(0);
```

`(void)(0)` is a no-op, achieving the expected behavior.

However, in this particular case, I'd recommend avoiding using a ternary operator. A classic `if...else` construct would be [more readable and appropriate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/ternary-operator-considered-harmful).

Comment: This still gives an error because `do {} while (0)` is a *statement* but not an *expression*. Something like `define NSLog(fmt, ...) (void)(0)` should work. - But I agree that `if ... else ...` should be preferred.

Comment: @MartinR Yep. I should have tested before posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove ";" at the end of the define.

```
#define NSLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"\n%s : [Line - %d] \n" fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```